# Is there a way to PM another user?

Tags: support, private-messaging

Well, the title says it all I apologize if its basic, but I really can't find it or even anything on it on meta.

The problem I had is that one user answers one of my questions and prior to that we had a long exchange over comments over it. Now the thing is I realized that one of my answers in that exchange gave him/her a bit of a wrong impression and I would have liked to clarify.

Would not really give anything to the wider SO, but but I think he/she would have liked to know... or at least I would have in their place.

In reality I do not think I am going to do that, we've exchange enough info on the matter, but it did get me thinking how do I *private message* another user if I need it for reason X.

Comment: See also: [Any way to send a personal message to another user?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user/433#433)

Comment: That meta change.... I searched in the wrong meta and did not even realize it...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is no way to have a *private* exchange with another user on the Stack Exchange (obviously you may do so through other services). You may create a chat room, and invite them to discuss something, but that is still going to be public and the conversation will remain indefinitely.