# Feature Request: StackFriends

Tags: feature-request

I'm sure this has been asked before, but a quick search found no results.

**Feature Request: StackFriends**

Is there any reason there's no way to connect with your friends/coworkers? Or private message them?

I ran across an answer from an old coworker and it would have been nice to reconnect with him on here other than just leaving a thanks comment and an inside-joke.

For the time being, I've simply added a **Friends** box to my profile description to keep track, but this isn't ideal.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261885/should-we-be-able-to-send-private-messages-to-other-users and http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250160/is-there-a-way-to-pm-another-user

Comment: Use `facebook` to connect with friends and `linkedin` to connect with coworkers.

Comment: There's even the convenient "share" link that gives you a link to share your questions on <insert social network here>. No need to re-invent the wheel

Comment: All of the nopes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [On large communities decaying over time, being nice or mean, and Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256084/839601):  "scaling by breaking the social network..."

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the related links, I understand now. Thanks all.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I know it seems like Stack Overflow has a lot of features in common with social networks, but the fact remains that it isn't one. I think most members of the community (and people who benefit from SO via Google hits) prefer if we keep focus on Questions and Answers, rather than Users.

Comment: Although, now that you mention it... allowing people to define their own circle of friends would probably make it a whole lot easier to bust up voting rings...

Comment: I thought we had chat for that?